# Chart.js need to fix x axis number of vales

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js JavaScript library for generating charts.

On my Yaxis I have float values and I am updating them after every one second.

On my Xaxis I have time line, actually I am displaying time line as data is updating after every second so no use of Xaxis time.

But my data keeps updating for n number of time and because of that as data increases my chart becomes unreadable and clumsy.

So I want to limit around 100 data points should be displayed at a given point. So every time graph displays <= 100 items at a time, even if I keep adding new data.

How this can be done using chart.js with simple line chart.

Answer (score 0):

The `time` axis type in ChartJS supports `min` and `max` - so you can work out what the oldest value you want displayed it and set its `x` value as `min`.

```
let data = [/* some data */]
data.sort((a, b) => a.x < b.x)

const min = data.length > 100 ? data[99].x : data[data.length - 1].x

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    min
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})
```